# How to handle Socket with Haxe/CPP

Tags: sockets, haxe

I'm trying to create a socket based communication with a server, with a Haxe client targetting CPP.

I'm looking at [sys.net.Socket](http://api.haxe.org/sys/net/Socket.html) that looks like what I want, but every methods is synchronous! How can I wait for a server event?

I'm used to Node syntax with `.on()` functions, is there any equivalent here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for non-blocking socket access in haxe/cpp:

1) Set the socket to non-blocking

With the [Socket.setBlocking](http://api.haxe.org/sys/net/Socket.html#setBlocking) method you set the blocking behavior of the socket. If set to `true`, which is the default, methods like `socket.accept()` (and likely `socket.read()` but I haven't personally tested it) will block until they complete.

But if you set blocking to `false`, those functions will throw if no data is available (you'll need to catch and move on.) So in your main loop you could access your non-blocking socket with try/catch around the `read()` calls.

2) Put your socket in a separate thread from your main loop

You can easily create a separate [Thread](http://api.haxe.org/cpp/vm/Thread.html) for your socket communcations, so then a blocking socket is fine. In this model, your socket thread will send data back to the main thread with `Thread.sendMessage()`, your main loop will check via `Thread.readMessage(block:Bool)` whether there's new data from the socket.

Comment: This could be what I need! I saw a snippet with the `read()` in a `while(true)` loop. Is that what your thread is doing?

Comment: Right, in a while loop, with blocking set to false, and a try/catch around read(), you can do whatever else you want without the socket blocking.

Comment: Working great! I'll just a small thread example because the documentation is not very clear on how to use them: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.joshuagranick.com/blog/2012/08/24/using-threads-with-nme/

Answer (score 2):

Historically hxcpp and async is arduous task as there is no hxcpp main loop out of the box, so the task is virtually always deferred to a toolkit ( openfl, nme etc...)

AFAIK there is no out of the box solution, binding http://zeromq.org/ might be a straghtforward and easy task thought.

You can also defer to HTTP implemtentations boxed with your favorite toolkit.

Good luck !